# How to exit an android app from any screen by using "back key" in android?

Tags: android

I'm new to android.. I'm creating a sample app with 2 pages.. simply I want to exit my app if I press "back key" in android from any screen.. for ex: consider that I'm in page 2 and I'm pressing back key, now I want my app to exit rather than going to page 1.

Answer (score 1):

**FYI** .

At first add finish method when calling Intent

```
Intent intOBJ = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intOBJ );
finish();
```

Then goto **ActivityB.class**

Add this **[onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())** method

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
     {
            super.onBackPressed();
            this.finish();
     }
```

> finish()->Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.
>   The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via
>   onActivityResult().

Comment: I am not agree with this. It will return to Activity 1.

Comment: @TruongHieu Kindly review my answer

Comment: You only call the launcher and finish 2nd activity, but the first one still there.

Comment: @TruongHieu then when launching new activity you must add `finish() ;`

Comment: where do I need to add this? in my activity 1 onBackPressed()? or in activity 2? @Amiya

Comment: @Vijay at first when you call Activity 2 add `finish();` and then goto Activity 2 and write `onBackPressed` method

Comment: I think like I'm confusing you @Amiya.. let me explain little more clearly.. I'm now in activity 2 and I want to go exit my app and I don't want this to take me to activity 1 instead.. I have tried your code but it takes me to Activity 1.

Comment: nope not yet..!! @Amiya

Answer (score 1):

Each activity you have to override onBackPressed method.
In this method you call a method name

## this.finish(); or finish();

Comment: I am not agree with this. It will return to Activity 1.

Comment: For this you must have to start  second activity like this.
`Intent intent = new Intent(this , secondActivity.this);
startActivity(intent);
finish();`

Answer (score 0):

Each activity you have to override `onBackPressed` method.

Then you type

```
finishAffinity();    
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: do not use `System.exit(0)` in android

Comment: @ShinilMS why not dude?

Comment: You should not call System.exit(). It could mess up Android's handling of the lifecycles of your activities and result in an awkward user-experience (e.g. when killing the process, the previous activity from which you launched your activity may be gone as well. Android may try to restart the process again and re-create that accidentally killed parent-activity)

Comment: I have tried using finish() in activity 2; but it is taking me to activity 1.. but I want my app to exit..

Comment: @ShinilMS you was correct.

Answer (score 0):

call `finish();` after you start an intent from an activity.

eg:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: I am not agree with this. It will return to Activity 1.

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Yes it is taking me to activity 1 from page2( or activity 2)

Comment: Sorry about that. I was wrong. It will finish the previous activity after starting new one. This can be an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Vijay show what you've done

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Use finish();